# When running hadoop example, I encountered ".staging/job_1541144755485_0002/job.splitmetainfo does not exist", what can I do?

Tags: hadoop

My configuration is below:
I used two machines for the Hadoop experiment, the pc720 (**10.10.1.1**) and the pc719 (**10.10.1.2**) respectively.
jdk(version 1.8.0_181) is installed by apt-get. **Hadoop2.7.1** is download from https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.1/, and put in **/opt/**

Step1:
I configured the /etc/bash.bashrc, adding

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64  
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}  
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-2.7.1  
export PATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}  
export PATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/sbin:${PATH}
```

and then run “`source /etc/profile`”

Step2:
I configure the xmls:

Slaves:

```
10.10.1.2
```

Core-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>fs.defautFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
        <value>131072</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/root/hadoop_store/tmp</value>
</property>
```

Hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs:replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/root/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/root/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
　　　　<name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
　　　　<value>10.10.1.1:9001</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
        <value>10.10.1.1:8080</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
        <value>10.10.1.1:9002</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
        <value>10.10.1.1:10020</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
        <value>10.10.1.1:19888</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapred.acls.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>10.10.1.1</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8090</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8033</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>8182</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
        <value>2.1</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Step3:
In /root/, established several directories:

```
mkdir hadoop_store
mkdir hadoop_store/hdfs
mkdir hadoop_store/tmp
mkdir hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode
mkdir hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode
```

Then I turned into /opt/Hadoop-2.7.1/bin, run

```
./hdfs namenode –format
cd ..
cd sbin/
./start-all.sh
./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

After run `jps`, pc720 shows

[image: jps on pc720]

pc719 shows

[image: jps on pc719]

Reaching here, I think my hadoop2.7.1 was successfully installed and configured. But the **problems** came.

I turned in /opt/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/ which shows

[image: directory]

Then I ran `hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar pi 2 2`

The logs are below

```
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 2
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
18/11/02 08:14:48 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.10.1.1:8032
18/11/02 08:14:48 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
18/11/02 08:14:48 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/11/02 08:14:48 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1541144755485_0002
18/11/02 08:14:49 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1541144755485_0002
18/11/02 08:14:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://node-0-link-0:8088/proxy/application_1541144755485_0002/
18/11/02 08:14:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1541144755485_0002
18/11/02 08:14:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1541144755485_0002 running in uber mode : false
18/11/02 08:14:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/11/02 08:14:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1541144755485_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1541144755485_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1541144755485_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://node-0-link-0:8088/cluster/app/application_1541144755485_0002Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1541144755485_0002/job.splitmetainfo does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1541144755485_0002/job.splitmetainfo does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
18/11/02 08:14:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Job Finished in 5.08 seconds
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/QuasiMonteCarlo_1541168087724_1532373667/out/reduce-out does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I have tried many solutions, but seemed useless. This problem has confused me for about 1 week. Are there any mistakes in my configuration? What can I do? Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking a question. Its good that you have tried to provide as much information as possible to explain your issue but it would be better if you can consolidate the question to have required information.

Comment: Try removing `hadoop.tmp.dir`, the default is fine

Comment: Also, Apache Ambari is a project that makes installing and managing Hadoop much easier

Comment: @qiang Did you have any luck solving this I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you missed a `/` a the end of`fs.defaultFS` value would be         `<value>hdfs://10.10.1.1:9000/</value>`

Note that `/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1541144755485_0002/job.splitmetainfo`  is configured by `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir` which is normally held in HDFS. This gives us a hint that is a HDFS problem.

SOURCE: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/cdh_ig_hdfs_cluster_deploy.html

Comment: I don't think that actually matters. Look at the Sample Configuration

Comment: It's correct that the sample configuration missed that `/`. Still the URI format expects a `/` at the end to point to the root path I believe, I always configured my hadoop cluster in such fashion. I might be wrong but it could worth a shot to try

Comment: I just tried your advice, but it made no sense. The logs were the same as what I shown in the question.

Comment: I see, I believe is a problem with HDFS or how it access HDFS.
`job.splitmetainfo` is saved at the HDFS by the client at the beginning of the jobs. How about `hadoop dfs -ls /tmp`

Comment: Also you might have to `stop-all.sh && start-all.sh` after making the change at the configs.

Answer (score 0):

By running `hadoop dfs -ls /tmp`, it shows

```
Found 17 items
drwxrwxrwt   - root root       4096 2018-11-01 22:33 /tmp/.ICE-unix
drwxrwxrwt   - root root       4096 2018-11-01 22:33 /tmp/.Test-unix
drwxrwxrwt   - root root       4096 2018-11-01 22:33 /tmp/.X11-unix
drwxrwxrwt   - root root       4096 2018-11-01 22:33 /tmp/.XIM-unix
drwxrwxrwt   - root root       4096 2018-11-01 22:33 /tmp/.font-unix
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-04 23:45 /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_50070_hdfs____w2cu08
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-04 23:45 /tmp/Jetty_10_10_1_1_8088_cluster____.kglkoh
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-04 23:46 /tmp/Jetty_node.0.link.0_19888_jobhistory____.ckp60y
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-04 23:45 /tmp/Jetty_node.0.link.0_9001_secondary____.h648yx
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-02 01:13 /tmp/hadoop-root
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          6 2018-11-04 23:45 /tmp/hadoop-root-namenode.pid
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          6 2018-11-04 23:45 /tmp/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode.pid
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-02 01:14 /tmp/hadoop-yarn
drwxr-xr-x   - root root       4096 2018-11-05 00:02 /tmp/hsperfdata_root
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          6 2018-11-04 23:46 /tmp/mapred-root-historyserver.pid
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        388 2018-11-01 22:33 /tmp/ntp.conf.new
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          6
```

Comment: Great, you can see that `/tmp/hadoop-root` is available. However Hadoop cannot access files inside: Possible reasons:

- Permissions
- Miss-configuration of Hadoop to connect to HDFS.

Comment: Other reason is that the task in the `pc719` cannot connect to its own DataNode. Can you check if its IP is well define to its localhost at `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: You can try to `hadoop dfs -ls /tmp` from `pc719` to check if it works from there