# The hadoop mapreduce example can sometimes work, sometimes fail, what happened?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I ran a hadoop mapreduce example by command

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount input output
```

and sometimes it worked:

```
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at node-0/10.10.1.1:8032
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1541484532513_0006
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1541484532513_0006
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://node-0:8088/proxy/application_1541484532513_0006/
18/11/06 00:37:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1541484532513_0006
18/11/06 00:37:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1541484532513_0006 running in uber mode : false
18/11/06 00:37:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/11/06 00:37:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/11/06 00:37:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
18/11/06 00:37:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1541484532513_0006 completed successfully
18/11/06 00:37:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 44
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=216
        FILE: Number of bytes written=231641
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1300
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=1265
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=1300
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=1265
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=1300
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=1265
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=1331200
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=1295360
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1
        Map output records=2
        Map output bytes=20
        Map output materialized bytes=30
        Input split bytes=135
        Combine input records=2
        Combine output records=2
        Reduce input groups=2
        Reduce shuffle bytes=30
        Reduce input records=2
        Reduce output records=2
        Spilled Records=4
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=14
        CPU time spent (ms)=660
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=402006016
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=4040646656
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=402653184
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=32
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=28
```

or logs may be below:

```
18/11/06 00:35:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1541484532513_0003_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_1541484532513_0003/job.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_1541484532513_0003/job.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


18/11/06 00:35:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1541484532513_0003_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_1541484532513_0003/job.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_1541484532513_0003/job.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


18/11/06 00:35:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/11/06 00:35:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
18/11/06 00:35:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1541484532513_0003 completed successfully
18/11/06 00:35:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 46
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=216
        FILE: Number of bytes written=231635
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=3
        Launched map tasks=4
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Other local map tasks=3
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=6266
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=1290
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=6266
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=1290
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=6266
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=1290
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=6416384
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=1320960
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1
        Map output records=2
        Map output bytes=20
        Map output materialized bytes=30
        Input split bytes=135
        Combine input records=2
        Combine output records=2
        Reduce input groups=2
        Reduce shuffle bytes=30
        Reduce input records=2
        Reduce output records=2
        Spilled Records=4
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=14
        CPU time spent (ms)=680
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=404619264
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=4036009984
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=402653184
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=32
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=28
```

It's weird! It should work with such a log! It said that job.jar doesn't exist.

But sometimes, it failed, with the same operations.

```
18/11/06 00:36:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1541484532513_0005_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_15414845
18/11/06 00:36:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1541484532513_0005_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_1541484532513_0005/job.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/suqiang/.staging/job_1541484532513_0005/job.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


18/11/06 00:36:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
18/11/06 00:36:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1541484532513_0005 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1541484532513_0005_r_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1

18/11/06 00:36:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 35
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=186
        FILE: Number of bytes written=115831
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Failed reduce tasks=4
        Launched map tasks=2
        Launched reduce tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=2217
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=8012
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=2217
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=8012
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=2217
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=8012
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=2270208
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=8204288
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1
        Map output records=2
        Map output bytes=20
        Map output materialized bytes=30
        Input split bytes=135
        Combine input records=2
        Combine output records=2
        Spilled Records=2
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=7
        CPU time spent (ms)=250
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=252555264
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2014208000
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=201326592
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=32
```

What happened to my experiment? Is it my mis-operation or the hadoop example's own probelems? Is there anyone who encountered the same problem? Any advice and solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is a continuation of the question at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53147682/2420872. There some possibilities has been covered so far

Comment: Sometimes Hadoop decides to run tasks in `uber` mode which means that their are run in the same process as the ApplicationMaster. In your questions in the first run is false how about in the second run, could you check in the job output?

Comment: I checked it and the mode was `uber`

Comment: And I can't find the job.jar in corresponding directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since your job fails when it is in uber mode, the problem lies in where the Application master cannot access HDFS or those folders in HDFS.

While we find the real solution to your problem you can disable `uber` mode for your job like this:

`hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar -D mapreduce.job.ubertask.enable=false  wordcount input output`

To fix the problem totally start by clearing up your ApplicationMaster *AM* configurations.

EDIT: Maybe your problem is in `/etc/hosts`. Could you print their contents in both of the machines. Maybe you dont have a mapping from `10.10.1.2` to `localhost` at `10.10.1.2` machine.

Comment: @qiang I wonder what happened with the problem, was it solved?